# How store dropdown selected option specific data to store in specific column in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, ssms

i have 2 tables emp and category .. In winform frontend, i have a dropdown box and its textbox .. I need to when select the option from dropdown its specific data in textbox enter to the specific column in database..In categoory table that have id and its category names it is fixed..so if i select one option in dropdown its correspond data entered to the main table.How can implement?

[image: i]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, perhaps show what you've done and explain what problems you're having.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to show in the TextBox, the phone number you select in the ComboBox. If so:

```
var phones = new List<Phone>
{
    new Phone("Business", "111111111"),
    new Phone("Mobile", "222222222"),
    new Phone("Home", "333333333")
};

var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = phones;

this.comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource.DataSource;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Type";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Number";

this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(
    "Text", bindingSource.DataSource, "Number", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

I don't know how are you storing your mobile numbers but I suppose you have the type of mobile and the number in your table. So, you can have a class with these two properties (probably with other properties, but no matter).

Then, you fill the Combobox with all your mobile numbers. To do that, set the DataSource of the combobox to your list of phones. You want to show the Type in the ComboBox (set DisplayMember) and the value associated to each ComboBox item will be the Number.

To show the number selected in the ComboBox, we set a DataBinding in the TextBox. We want to set Text property of TextBox (first parameter), using the data of the CombobBox (dataSource un second parameter) and fill with the Number property.

Your Phone class maybe something like this:

```
public class Phone
{
    public Phone(string type, string number)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Number = number;
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```